# Parse .proto to php class

Tags: php, parsing, protocol-buffers

I've currently trying to parse a .proto file into php. I've tried using [DrSlump's Protobuf Parser](https://github.com/drslump/Protobuf-PHP)
but either my knowledge is too small or my Godaddy Shared Hosting is missing something. I've tried everything with my knowledge with no success to get what I want.

So my Question, is there any step by step tutorial on how to get this working?

I've got protoc installed with SSH and also installed

```
pear channel-discover pear.pollinimini.net
pear install drslump/Protobuf-beta
```

Current issue:

```
root@v0071:~/Root/var/www/xxx.com/web/test# protoc-gen-php
Protobuf-PHP 0.9.4 by Ivan -DrSlump- Montes

Error: You must provide at least 1 argument.

Type "/usr/bin/protoc-gen-php --help" to get help.
root@v0071:~/Root/var/www/xxx.com/web/test# php protoc-gen-php.php LandData.proto
Protobuf-PHP @package_version@ by Ivan -DrSlump- Montes

/var/www/clients/client1/web10/web/test/LandData.proto: 
File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).    
You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  
Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of 
the .proto file names --protoc is too dumb to figure out when two 
paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent 
(it's harder than you think).

ERROR: protoc exited with an error (1) when executed with: 
protoc \--plugin=protoc-gen-php='/var/www/clients/client1/
web10/web/test/protoc-gen-php.php' \

--proto_path='/var/www/clients/client1/web10/web/test/
library/DrSlump/Protobuf/Compiler/protos' \--php_out=':./' \
'/var/www/clients/client1/web10/web/test/LandData.proto'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question is old, I thought of answering and maybe someone will find it helpful.

First i would recommend you to use the official library from the [`Protobuf`](https://github.com/google/protobuf) github repository.

So what I understand is that you are trying to generate PHP clases from a proto file. To do that you must first install protocol buffer compiler([protoc](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases)). At the end of the link you can find the releases.

The easiest way to install `protoc` is by using the binaries and afterwards, you can compile the file once you are in the `"/protobufBinaries/bin"` and you will find `protoc` there.

Now that you have protoc, you can run: `./protoc --php_out=/var/www/html/generated_files /var/www/html/proto/example.proto --proto_path=/var/www/html/proto`

***NOTE: Do not forget to specify the --proto_path otherwise it will give an error. You need to specify the same path but dont have to include the file.** `You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.`*

In my case, the classes were generated in `/var/www/html/generated_files`.

Good luck